# Visual Studio 2008 compiler macro reference or tutorial?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

Does anyone know the location of a good list or tutorial showing all the compiler macros (_T etc) in use in Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here:

- a starting point for C++ specific: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/503x3e3s(v=VS.80).aspx
- a general list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay(VS.80).aspx
- a starting point for MFC: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2dch7fb(v=VS.100).aspx